# JSON-schema from abstract schema definition

Tags: jsonschema

I have [this](https://gist.github.com/Shmookoff/0edeaaa2987d4a7f5a3e3fc09003fe13) JSON *abstract?* schema that was parsed from the table [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Sample:

```py
{
    "kind": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Identifies what kind of resource this is. Value: the fixed string \"drive#file\".",
        "Notes": ""
    },
    "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The ID of the file.",
        "Notes": "writable"
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The name of the file. This is not necessarily unique within a folder. Note that for immutable items such as the top level folders of shared drives, My Drive root folder, and Application Data folder the name is constant.",
        "Notes": "writable"
    },
    "sharingUser.kind": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Identifies what kind of resource this is. Value: the fixed string \"drive#user\".",
        "Notes": ""
    },
    "sharingUser.displayName": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "A plain text displayable name for this user.",
        "Notes": ""
    }
}
```

How can I easily turn it into a full JSON schema with references and all that stuff?

I *could* just use schema generators from JSON data, but using them, you lose descriptions.

*I understand there probably is a question about that, haven't managed to find it though.*

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. Start with a small sample of your input data, and the expected result, and then write some code to do the transformations.

Comment: Please add the content for the basis of your question INTO the question itself. External links can get broken.

Comment: @Ether this does not really help..

Comment: @Relequestual whole schema is kinda big to put in question body.. I updated it with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. It's ugly, but gets the job done.

If you want to parse the Properties of, lets say, `sharingUser`, you set `DISCRIMINATOR` to `sharingUser.` (with period).

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("./common/folder/")
desc_path = Path(path, "desc.json")
output_path = Path(path, "output.json")

DISCRIMINATOR = "sharingUser."
NOT_IN = ["."]
DEPRECATED = "Warning: This item is deprecated."
desc: dict[str, dict] = dict(json.loads(desc_path.read_text("utf-8")))


class Types:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.mapping = {"long": "integer", "list": "array"}

    def get_type(self, __name: str):
        return self.mapping.get(__name, __name)


output = {"properties": {}}
types = Types()

for name, prop in desc.items():
    if name.startswith(DISCRIMINATOR) and not (DEPRECATED in prop["description"]):
        name = name.replace(DISCRIMINATOR, "")
        if not any(x in name for x in NOT_IN):
            title = name
            type = types.get_type(prop["type"])
            description = prop["description"].replace("  ", "\n")
            if prop["Notes"]:
                description += f"\n\n.. note:\n    {prop['Notes']}"

            output["properties"][name] = {
                "title": name,
                "type": type,
                "description": description,
            }


output_path.write_text(json.dumps(output), "utf-8")
```

The output would be json file with jsonschema "properties" object.